# How to generate an Octomap from a Point Cloud with Hydro?

Tags: octomap, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My configuartion: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS + ROS Hydro

Hi, how is possible to create an Octomap (.ot or .bt) from a point cloud file (.pcd)?

could someone please give me some suggestion, please?

I'm asking this because I am new to the ROS (I'm following a robotics class and the teacher assigned me this homework), I know that it's possible in Fuerte thanks to the octomap_server, so now I am trying to install octomap_mapping in ros-hydro (with some trouble), but i'm wondering if some Ros Guru have any suggestions for me.

I would like to emphasize that I'm not asking you to do my homework but to give me a sort of guideline to follow, since it seems that Hydro is a pretty new distro.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89906/how-to-generate-an-octomap-from-a-point-cloud-with-hydro?/) by [jhonhyd](https://answers.ros.org/users/7661/jhonhyd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try the "hydro-devel" branch of octomap_mapping at GitHub:
https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping/tree/hydro-devel

It has a catkinized version for ROS Hydro that you need to source-install in your workspace. If I get some feedback I can properly release a version for ROS hydro.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jhonhyd](https://answers.ros.org/users/7661/jhonhyd/) on 2013-10-14**:
Thanks for the reply.

I compiled the "hydro-devel" branch of octomap_mapping.

However, I created a test node for reading the point cloud file and publish it on the "cloud_in" topic, but the "octomap_server" don't receive the message, it seems that the "tf" roscore feature is working like a filter. It's possible that this is caused by the message's header? If yes, How can I set the msg's header in order to get it seen by the octomap_server node? Thanks again.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-10-16**:
If you just want to convert a PCD file to octree, then it may be easier to write a short node that uses the OctoMap API directly. Simply loop through the end points, create a PointCloud out of it and insert it into the octree (see http://octomap.github.io/octomap/doc/).

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-10-16**:
For octomap_server you need a valid TF tree to the sensor frame (header of your pointcloud) from the given map frame.